# Android splash-screen not visible

Tags: android

My splash screen shows up in genymotion, but on a real android device the screen is just white for 5 seconds.

The layout is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/launchphone"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

the code for the activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private DownloadAPITask task;
    private String response;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(getResources().getConfiguration().isLayoutSizeAtLeast(Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE)){
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }else{
            setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        task = new DownloadAPITask(this, null, new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){

                onAPIDownload();
            }
        });
        task.execute(new APIRequest("http://my-site.com/api/", "request=asd"));
    }

    private void onAPIDownload(){
        StringBuilder strb = task.getResponse();
        if(strb == null){
            response = null;
        }else{
            response = strb.toString();
        }
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                launch();
            }
        }, 2000);
    }

    private void launch(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, StartActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(StartActivity.API, response);

        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

drawable/launchphone is a .png file located in res/drawable/ not in any of the dpi-dependent drawable locations, since it is just to be scaled fullscreen. I'm assuming from the lengthy start-up time on a real device that it's the splash screen but instead of rendering this image it just shows up white.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you are launching the Splash Activity, wait, terminate it, and finally launch the Main Activity

Comment: Do you get Response ??

Answer (score 0):

You have to: `import android.os.Handler;`

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable){
   @Override
   public void run() {
      Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NextActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);
       ThisActivity.this.finish();
    },1000);
}
```

You can write any time duration of the splash screen. (in this case time=1000 millisecond)